# How do you access the "point of interest" that appear on the map?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I see the point of interest on the map and head there and nothing happens. What are these? Is anything supposed to happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A point of interest is just a pointer (or saved spot) you (in your case accidentally) placed on the map.

You can remove them by pressing Y or Triangle when it is selected on your map.